# A dll with a vector of vectors. in one of its classes methods

Tags: c++, arrays, dll, vector

In my c++ program i'm trying to create a dll that houses the functionality of my a* algorithm.
I encounter a problem when trying to pass the map into it, I first tried to use a 2d array, but that limited my map sizes, so i'm now trying to use a vector in a vector and I keep hitting some odd snag.

In my dlls .h file:

```
namespace IInterface
{
class IInterface
{
public:
    // Sets the map
    static __declspec(dllexport) void setMap(int h, int w,vector<vector<byte>> &myarray);
private:
    static vector<vector<byte>> mymap;
}
```

Finaly in the .cpp i have:

```
#include "IInterface.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

namespace IInterface
{
void IInterface::setMap(int h, int w,vector<vector<byte>> &myarray)
{
    mymap = myarray;
}
}
```

Im getting a few errors on compilation even tho the code looks fine to me.

```
error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'vector' c:\users\steven\documents\github\schooladvgdproject\game code\deathastardll\iinterface.h    7   1   DMAstarDLL
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'  c:\users\steven\documents\github\schooladvgdproject\game code\deathastardll\iinterface.h    21  1   DMAstarDLL
error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'  c:\users\steven\documents\github\schooladvgdproject\game code\deathastardll\iinterface.h    21  1   DMAstarDLL
error C2511: 'void IInterface::IInterface::setMap(int,int,std::vector<_Ty> &)' : overloaded member function not found in 'IInterface::IInterface'   c:\users\steven\documents\github\schooladvgdproject\game code\deathastardll\iinterface.cpp  13  1   DMAstarDLL
error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   c:\users\steven\documents\github\schooladvgdproject\game code\deathastardll\iinterface.h    21  1   DMAstarDLL
```

I looked at some samples, but there was really nothing that matched this scenario. I have a sneaking suspicion i'm forgetting something crucial, but I cant see it. Ideas on getting this to work?

Comment: Passing a std::*anything* across a DLL boundary with no ABI defined for the library (the standard lib doesn't have one) is generally a bad idea unless you're projects are forever-conjoined. (and even then, be *very* careful).

Comment: @WhozCraig What would you recomend then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your dlls.h does not include vector type - you should tell the compiler vector definition and include .

Tip: don't use using namespace std; in header file only in cpp. Instead of this use std::vector ...etc.

Secondly, be careful when your dll interface contains stl. This library differs as regards Release and Debug versions, so if you load Release dll in Debug program you could have problems.

Comment: Ok so i added the include to the .h and no dice. Secondly, when i do std::vector i get an error about std not containing vector. Finaly, stl?

Comment: Alright, i striped it down removed using namespace std; and replaced all instances of vector with std::vector that cleared up the errors, but now i receive a linking error.    Error 1 error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: static class std::vector<class std::vector<char,class std::allocator<char> >,class std::allocator<class std::vector<char,class std::allocator<char> > > > IInterface::IInterface::mymap" (?mymap@IInterface@1@0V?$vector@V?$vector@DV?$allocator@D@std@@@std@@V?$allocator@V?$vector@DV?$allocator@D@std@@@std@@@2@@std@@A)

Comment: Alright, fixed needed to do: std::vector<std::vector<char>> IInterface::mymap; in the cpp

Comment: '#include <vector>

class IInterface
{
public:
 typedef std::vector< std::vector<byte> > matrix_t; 

 static __declspec(dllexport)  void setMap(int h, int w, matrix_t &myarray);
private:
    static matrix_t mymap;
};'

Comment: #include "dlls.h"

void IInterface::setMap(int h, int w, matrix_t &myarray)
{
    mymap = myarray;
}